# Remove time portion when display date model by Wicket Label

Tags: hibernate, wicket

I am new to wicket. I want to display a date which I get from database by hibernate, and display it by a simple Label.

```
Label("nextCallDate",new PropertyModel(contact, "nextCallDate"))
```

But the problem is I only want to display the date, and omit the time portion. Are there any ways to do this? Or even further, are there any ways to format the output of Label components?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass the `PropertyModel` and create a model that will return a formatted string using DateFormatUtils from Apache Commons. This has the advantage that you dont have to modify your entities and it's easier for reuse.

```
public class DatePropertyModel extends PropertyModel{

    public DatePropertyModel(Object modelObject, String expression) {
        super(modelObject, expression);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getObject() {
        return DateFormatUtils.format((Date)super.getObject(), "dd-MM-yyyy"); 
    }

}
```

Then you define your label using this model class

```
Label("nextCallDate",new DatePropertyModel(contact, "nextCallDate"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an IConverter for that. You can register one on your Application or override #getConverter() on your component.